# Javascript object.id returning "undefined" in array of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the ids of any array of elements grabbed by the class name. I've tried several different ways, all of which I believe should work, but each way returns "undefined".

example of html:

```
<img id='1207_image-button' class='review-button' src="..." />
```

javascript:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("review-button");
var button;
for (button in buttons) { alert(button.id); }
```

I've also tried this is the for loop:

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

Each way returns "undefined", i'm not sure how to alert the actual id. If I put this in the loop:

```
alert(button);
```

It will loop through and output 0 through 5 (the number of elements) then output the ids so I know then are in the array I just don't know how to get to it.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Because `$(this).attr('id')` won't work in plain JS.

Comment: @DavidThomas - right, but in a passive-aggressive sort of way I like to get people to realize that they need to correctly tag their own question. Teach a man to fish, blah, blah, blah...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for...in` loop are used to iterate over objects. Not `NodeList`, which is not even an array. Use a good old `for` loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
   alert(buttons[i].id);
```

Comment: A way to trouble shoot this type of problem is to console.log() the object in question.  If you use this method in the original situation, you will see that button would not allow you to access the id property.

Answer (score 1):

By using `for ... in` you're incorrectly iterating through the collection of buttons.  Try this, instead:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("review-button");
for (var i = 0, n = buttons.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var id = buttons[i].id;
    ...
}
```

or alternately, in jQuery

```
$('.review-button').each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using jquery use this;

```
$( ".review-button" ).each(function() {
  alert($( this ).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id') === this.id`

Answer (score 0):

the wrong part is the loop. 
You have to do:

```
for (button in buttons) { alert(buttons[button].id); }
```

in this kind of loop, you assign the index of array, not the object in each cycle.